Why does applying sign convention in derivation of lens formula work?
So in the derivation of the lens formula that is 1/f = 1/u + 1/v, we consider one case and then to generalize we use sign convention. Why is this possible? We only know that the given equation is true for the one case we have. When we use sign convention don't we have to prove that it also holds for all other cases?
Let us take byju's derivation for the lens formula

From the given figure, we notice that △ABO and △A’B’O are similar.
Therefore,
\begin{array}{l}\frac{A’B’}{AB}=\frac{OB’}{OB}     (1)\end{array}
Similarly, △A’B’F and △OCF are similar, hence
\begin{array}{l}\frac{A’B’}{OC}=\frac{FB’}{OF}\end{array}
But,
\begin{array}{l}OC=AB\end{array}
Hence,
\begin{array}{l}\frac{A’B’}{AB}=\frac{FB’}{OF}        (2)\end{array}
Equating eq (1) and (2), we get
\begin{array}{l}\frac{OB’}{OB}=\frac{FB’}{OF}=\frac{OB’-OF}{OF}\end{array}
Substituting the sign convention, we get
OB=-u,  OB’=v and OF=f
\begin{array}{l}\frac{v}{-u}=\frac{v-f}{f}\end{array}
I have a problem with this step. We only know that the equation \begin{array}{l}\frac{OB’}{OB}=\frac{FB’}{OF}=\frac{OB’-OF}{OF}\end{array} works for the given case above. How can we generalize for all cases?
For full derivation: https://byjus.com/physics/derivation-of-lens-formula/

More on sign conventions for lenses.

If you don't like the shortcut of exploiting the negative half of the real number line, you are always welcome, and in fact encouraged, to rederive the relation for the other case and show that the sign convention neatly encapsulates the correct behaviour.

You can always try out the other cases, but you'll see the same results in all. Unfortunately, this doesn't satisfy me enough for an answer tho.

There are a number of sign conventions for lenses and your question is more difficult to answer as you have not stated what byju's sign convention is.
All lens sign conventions start with one formula connecting focal length, image distance and object distance which, when used in conjunction with the corresponding sign convection, correctly predicts what happens in all cases.
Thus, in a sense, you start with the formula, eg I also use $1/f = +1/u+1/v$ (note this one differs from your one) and produce a sign convention so that that one formula correctly predicts a correct outcome in all situations.
To check, draw the ray diagram for an object inside the focal length of a convex lens, do the geometry and apply byju's sign convention and you will get byju's lens formula $1/f = -1/u+1/v$.

No my question is, why does the formula itself hold true in all these different cases in the first place. You say that the formula comes first and then for all the cases, the signs are adjusted for it to be true but why does the formula work in those cases? Is it just brute force that is someone checked all the cases or is there some deeper reason.

Some clever Physicist made sure that the formula they chose and the associated sign convention worked for all situations. Have you tried the example I suggested?
